# Batch operation with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Do SqlTransaction's perform a batch operation without repetitive access to the database? I don't know since SqlTransaction seems to group a bunch of SQL commands together and finally commit to the database. However, every command would run an ExecuteNonQuery(), which results in a database access.

```
public List<Task> SubmitSheet(List<Task> tList)
{
    SqlConnection conn = A2.Controller.Utils.conn;
    SqlTransaction submitTransaction = null;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        submitTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        foreach (Task t in tList) {
            SqlCommand submitCmd = new SqlCommand("SubmitTask", conn);
            submitCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            submitCmd.Transaction = submitTransaction;
            submitCmd.Parameters.Add("@tid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = t.Id;
            submitCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        submitTransaction.Commit();
    }        
    finally {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
    }
    return tList;
}
```

Comment: no it does not - just test with your favorite Sql-Profiler. BTW: this has nothing todo with asp.net

Comment: If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use table valued parameters to submit the batch of ids to the stored procedure altogether.

Comment: @CKoenig You means, it will access the database for every command?

Comment: Have a look at SqlBulkCopy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx#Y1536 It's very useful (and fast) for inserting large numbers or rows at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as @CKoenig says it will access the database for every command. If you want to batch the commands try to use `SqlDataAdapter.AddToBatch` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx.